# November 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest #2

Tags: discussion, election

The following is a "digest" version of the [November 2011 Moderator Election Town Hall Chat #2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111863/november-2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chats-scheduled). The format, [as described on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests), is one *answer* to this question *for every question* asked in the Town Hall, containing all the candidate's answers to that question.

Be sure to also check out the [digest from the earlier session](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112443/november-2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest-1).

**To view the digest chronologically, please sort the answers by "oldest"**.

If you have questions or comments about this, **please do not answer this question** as the answers are designed to be used for the questions from the Town hall itself. Instead, please ask on [the parent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests) or in [the Town Hall Discussion Room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/352/town-hall-discussion).

If you see any corrections which need to be made to this digest, or if you were a candidate who was unable to attend the town hall and would like your answers included, please @Rebecca or @TimStone [in the chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/505/town-hall-chat) and let us know!

Answer (score 4):

### *[image: Tim Post] [Tim Post](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888067#1888067) [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock):* If elected, you and I would be the only moderators in our time zone. Do you have any ideas on how we could promote Stack Overflow in SE Asia?

---

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888118#1888118):** Aside from what [@StuThompson said](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888105#1888105) (which I agree with), I can only think of spreading word of SO via social media, and in my school, for now. I don't know many programmers beyond these two.

- **[image: Tim Post] [Tim Post](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888148#1888148) [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock):** Would you have the time to help organize events, since the whole concept of DevDays is basically NULL at this point?

  **[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888161#1888161):** I'm not good at that stuff, to be honest...

Answer (score 3):

### *[image: phwd] [phwd](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/321505/phwd) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888769#1888769):* There are a lot of high views / highly voted questions that are closed as "Not Constructive", what is your stance on this? Throw them under the rug (i.e. leave them), edit so it could be reopened (if so how) or kill it with fire (delete)?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888776#1888776):** Leave them for now.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888799#1888799):** If they can be edited to be constructive then edit them.  However, if they cannot, then leave them, they serve as a bellwether for what isn't accepted/what not to do on the site.

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888809#1888809):** That all depends on the question. Just because it has high views or votes doesn't make it a good fit for the site. If breaches what is defined in the FAQ then there is no point in trying to save it.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888818#1888818):** I leave them alone. I still find these very controversial, and touchy, and I'd rather not touch them in case I get a "shock".

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888864#1888864):** Edit them if possible.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888906#1888906):** Leave them.  I'm loath to straight-up delete content that has some value and that people have put significant amounts of time into.  I do like some of the edits and comments that other moderators have placed on these older questions, indicating that they were once appropriate for the site but are no longer accepted.  This seems to be a fine way to not have these be broken windows, yet still have them survive.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889238#1889238):** It depends what value the question delivers by still existing. closed/locked is a sensible status for questions which were topical and were interesting, but the community sense of "topical" has shifted.

**[image: slugster] [slugster](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/109702/slugster) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1890660#1890660):** As I mentioned in my moderator spiel, this is an area that needs to be cleaned up. However I do believe that some of these old questions need to be preserved because they are part of the fabric and history of SO, and some of them can be quite enlightening or educational.

Answer (score 3):

### *[image: Adam Davis] [Adam Davis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888873#1888873):* Do you miss TheTXI or RichB or both? (if you don't know who they are/were, you may safely ignore this question)

---

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888889#1888889):** I'm not sure what they are

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888895#1888895):** Guess i am not old enough to know who they are...

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888904#1888904):** Miss, no, but at the same time, I think it's important for users like that (in small doses), as it helps the site grow and learn.  If the site isn't challenged, then it won't evolve.

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: random] [random](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888109#1888109):* Why was the Yearling badge a good requirement for nominations, even if it was later withdrawn?

---

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888113#1888113):** I don't think it was a good requirement, that's why it was removed

- **[image: Tim Cooper] [Tim Cooper](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/142162/tim-cooper) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888134#1888134) [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis):** Can you elaborate on why you feel it wasn't?

  **[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888150#1888150):** Because even me (5 month Stack Overflow participant) know the most of used practices and know most of the tools offered by Stack Overflow. Sure, there are a lot of things I had to learn, and I still have, but I think that I'm experienced enough to handle the duties

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888122#1888122):** I understand that it was a rule originally and I petitioned for it to be removed ([Should Moderator Election rules be changed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111256/should-moderator-election-rules-be-changed)) because I felt that it was not just for users who have been here longer to have a better chance than the others.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888136#1888136):** Because just because you are hear more than a year, does not mean you have more or less experience in moderating SO (or any site)

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888144#1888144):** I think it was a good requirement, but I'm not upset it was removed.  It allowed for some people who are obviously capable to step up to the role.  Right now, we need moderators, and we need qualified ones.  Time is something we can't change.  It's only an indicator of how long we've had to learn, not *how much*

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888146#1888146):** The yearling badge was a reasonable suggestion because there are some events that are comparatively rare. extra time increases the odds of witnessing rarer events and increases familiarity with the community.

**[image: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ] [NullUserException ఠ_ఠ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888147#1888147):** I believe the Yearling requirement should've stayed. Users who have been members for less than a year don't understand the site well enough to moderate it (nor does the rest of the users know the mod-to-be well enough). At least that's my opinion.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888159#1888159):** I would argue yes, despite how discriminatory that might sound.  For example, I ran for moderator last year and didn't make the primary cutoff, yet I feel better capable of doing the job now than I was a year ago (despite being a member for 3 years).  Requiring people to have significant experience with the site and its standards is not a bad thing for moderators.

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888214#1888214):** I think the Yearling was a good requirement and should not have been removed. It shows that you are willing to put in some kind effort to visit the site. A year is a long time and you get to see a lot of different situations that may occur. It doesn't mean that you always know the right answer but with more exposure to these situations the better you will be reading them and how to handle them.

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888246#1888246):** The Yearling badge was a good requirement for Community Moderators because less than a year is likely too short to establish a track record of past behavior.  But it's a fine point and not something I stress about.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889207#1889207):** The yearling badge does make sense a requirement because it guarantees a baseline of experience with the system.

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: OffBySome] [OffBySome](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/265570/offbysome) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888166#1888166) [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis):* Why do you think you are racking up way more down-votes than anyone else?

---

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888172#1888172):** Because sometimes I'm just wrong. I'm still learning and do mistakes

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: Adam Davis] [Adam Davis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888304#1888304):* Do you see your role as primarily dealing with issues other users bring to you, or will you be "out on the streets" so to speak, actively policing posts?  Describe what makes the difference for you between letting the users guide the site, and you taking unilateral action on items not yet flagged.

---

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888356#1888356):** There are obvious situations where an item needs to be flagged; rude or offensive content, content that obviously doesn't belong (something purely subjective, violating NDA, etc).  Those things need to be actively policed.  Other things, the community can handle, but I will police them in the event the community misses them.

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888379#1888379):** I don't think moderators should be actively seeking out posts to police. If you stumble across one then fair enough.  There is enough community members to deal with the day to day normal stuff. Moderators should be there to deal with exceptional circumstances - situations where its not possible for "normal" users to resolve or when a situation is getting out of hand.  That is what the flag for moderator button is for.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888386#1888386):** Actively policing posts is not the role of moderators, who should be human exception handlers.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888389#1888389):** At first, I'd probably be content to handle some of the flagging load and not seek out additional problematic items.  The community lately has been doing an extremely good job of identifying content (I've had a hard time finding things to flag that aren't already within the last few weeks).

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888399#1888399):** Actively policing, but only taking serious action if there are large, obvious issues.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888460#1888460):** I'd rather avoid unilateral action in all but the most obvious cases ("NIKE TRAINERS CHEAP") - I am fairly "on the streets" in the tags that interest me though

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889478#1889478):** That's what the 10k and mod tools are for, no? If I see something that needs to be dealt with, it's silly not to do so simply because "nobody else flagged it yet", but again, case by case is an important consideration.

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: quantumSoup] [quantumSoup](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/370483/quantumsoup) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888636#1888636):* Bill Gates passes away during your tenure as a moderator. You feel he deserves a banner like the one Steve Jobs got. What do you do? Or, some other mod puts a banner for him. Users are irate on meta saying that Dennis Ritchie didn't get his. Do you remove the banner?

---

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888651#1888651):** I would first discuss it on meta, and with other moderators.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888660#1888660):** That's a substantial site change which I feel should be brought up in meta; users *will* sound off about it in meta, and action (by me or someone else) will be taken based on the way the wind blows there.

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888670#1888670):** Remove the banner. They should be there for important site or network messages. Adding a "memorial" banner just irritates people a) It's there and distracting b) They don't think the person mentioned deserves it or c) The banner isn't there for such a person or other.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888690#1888690):** If I recall correctly, the Jobs one was posted by Jeff, without the interaction of the moderators.  I would not feel that it was my place to post something like this, unless there was an overwhelming consensus to do so.  The debate over the last one is still continuing.

- **[image: Paŭlo Ebermann] [Paŭlo Ebermann](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/600500/paulo-ebermann) [noted](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888710#1888710):** Actually, it was posted by Joel while Jeff was away.

  **[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [corrected](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888724#1888724):** Sorry, misremembered this.  In any case, it wasn't a moderator-level decision and I think it should remain as such.

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888701#1888701):** Moderators can set banners?  That sounds dangerous, only "the powers that be" should have that kind of power...not mere demi-god-like moderators.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888702#1888702):** I feel that the banners are meant for site announcements, **and nothing else**. A rule of thumb I think about is that if doesn't even come close to being on meta, neither does it on the banner.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888946#1888946):** I'm not in the business of designing banners or deciding who is most famous

**[image: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ] [NullUserException ఠ_ఠ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1892564#1892564):** I was the first one to point out the Jobs banners was not appropriate in the first place and I got an avalanche of negative responses for that. Of course, after the "Dennis Ritchie debacle" [some people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109160/dennis-ritchie-goes-into-the-night-without-a-quote-on-stack-overflow/109225#109225) realized it wasn't such a great idea after all. I am strongly opposed to (ab)using the system message feature for "memorials."

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: Robert Harvey] [Robert Harvey](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888924#1888924):* Jeff Atwood has a super-veto for issues raised on Meta ("The community is run by YOU" notwithstanding).  Have you ever disagreed with any of his [status-declined] decisions (which ones?), and how would this affect your moderation?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888941#1888941):** I have disagreed. I was once banned from asking questions on Meta due to all the poor results from the ones I already had. I had emailed support for SO and Jeff responded and got my meta account active again.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888963#1888963):** Ahhh but this meta Q has always been annoying me that Jeff did reject: [Create comment-spawned chatrooms for the post, not for the users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98926/create-comment-spawned-chatrooms-for-the-question-not-for-the-users)

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888947#1888947):** The only time I disagreed with him, he stepped back, and changed his decision.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888951#1888951):** I can't recall any decision I've been in violent disagreement with.  Even if I did, it wouldn't be something that impacts me.  Disagreements are a part of life, this is no different, and Jeff does have that authority, which I respect.

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888972#1888972):** Yes, I've disagreed with some of Jeff's decisions.  But that's part of team work: not everyone can have their way at all times.  That the way the cookie crumbles, as my mother used to say...

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888978#1888978):** Few of them, but I don't think I have enough time to look back at his answers and find these I don't agree with

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889026#1889026):** None of them were concerned about the moderation

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889014#1889014):** I haven't gotten him to follow up on one of my meta questions, but that was about a technical issue with the site so I doubt it'd affect my moderation.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889025#1889025):** I can't dig up the Meta issues that I've disagreed with him on, but I do recall emailing the team and having an argument back in the day about the value of votes on questions vs. votes on answers.  I thought they should count less on questions and he did not. In the end, he did respond to the community and lowered the question vote value. As with everyone, be polite and explain your reasoning clearly.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889409#1889409):** I dislike that so far all of the "block bad migrations by X" have been declined. Some bad migrations are painful to watch (although can often be averted by a plain vote to close + a mod flag and comment). I don't think that's a big problem though!

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ] [NullUserException ఠ_ఠ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888087#1888087):* All of you have amassed a fairly large amount of reputation. If you are elected, how are you going to balance your time between posting answers and moderating?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888103#1888103):** I do not plan on posting as much. But when It comes to it I believe that if I see a great question that needs answering, i will post. otherwise i would stay on with mod duty

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888106#1888106):** Handling moderator duties would be the first thing I would do.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888107#1888107):** Moderator duties come first.  My current actions lean mostly towards editing, etc (I just moved 100+ entries from the ASP tag to ASP.NET or ASP-CLASSIC for example).  However, the pursuit of rep is not important to me at this point (as stated in my nomination), so moderator duties come first.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888114#1888114):** My time for answering to questions will not change, but moderating will not become my predominant task.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888123#1888123):** See my previous answer for more, but I don't post many answers nowadays and instead focus on cleaning things up.  Reputation no longer has the same draw for me as it once did, and I care more about maintaining the site as a great resource.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888128#1888128):** I wouldn't devote less time to answering questions, just more time to moderating. I have plenty of time.

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888127#1888127):** I don't feverishly answer questions like I did in the early days.  The FGITW behavior annoys me.  I tend to comb through older questions and answer them.  That's the same time when I clean stuff up with edits, comments and the occasional flag.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888133#1888133):** My posting activities would shift towards answering older, unanswered questions, or questions where the current answers were lacking and I have specific knowledge that would be benificial

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889174#1889174):** As I answered @MrDisappontment, I'd probably spend larger amounts of time moderating than asking/answering. Moderating is a responsibility, but also a privilege - which I'd like to take advantage of, given the opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Adam Davis] [Adam Davis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888162#1888162):* Consider an online argument you've had in the past.  1) What about the argument made you respond so passionately - was it the topic, the way the other person presented it, or something else? 2) How long (# of responses or time) did the argument last? 3) How did it end (in terms of who ended it, and how did the contenders part ways - amicably, or otherwise)?

---

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888197#1888197):** It was how horribly rude the person was being. The argument lasted about 5 comments on each side, and eventually I stopped responding. I haven't seen the user since, either.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888239#1888239):** Usually it's my passion for the topic at hand that fueled the argument.  I'll also attribute my youth to it.  I've been out of the business of flame wars for a while. =)  To say it was the way the other person presented it is a little bit of a cop out; it takes two to tango.  As I got older, the arguments didn't last, and eventually became non-existent, and I ultimately got to the point where I was big enough to say when I was wrong or approached the debate wrong.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888256#1888256):** 1) technical advice that was faulty/flawed 2) I aim to state my case clearly and then leave it at that (or possibly ask a follow up question if it's ambiguous and interesting enough in its own right). sometimes I'll clarify things further if I feel the problem was a communication one and not simply who can shout the loudest - this means typically fairly short 3) amicably agree to disagree on implications of problem

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888297#1888297):** 1) Mostly the topic, about a certain controversial technology topic. 2) Just a 10-minute Twitter conversation. 3) Agree to disagree.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889331#1889331):** I try to shy away from arguments, but I've [had a disagreement about adding a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108703/can-we-please-also-support-google-plus-syntax-for-mentions). The argument lasted less than 5 comments.  I can be passionate, but I usually don't have arguments. Thinking about it more, I [have gotten burned on several feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78359/handling-rtfm-questions).

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: mizo] [mizo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/287954/mizo) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888210#1888210):* What makes you enjoy moderating and janitorial tasks?

---

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888235#1888235):** The fact I am doing something useful for the SE site I am moderating, which is the reason I use 10k tools, and review posts.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888237#1888237):** Helps improve the community ^_^

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888243#1888243):** Taking a terrible piece of content and turning it into something good. It gives a great sense of accomplishment :)

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888244#1888244):** I just love to clean the posts & titles in the titles

**[image: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ] [NullUserException ఠ_ఠ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888250#1888250):** I am bit OCD when it comes to keeping the site clean.  I already do it now, through edits and flags, becoming a moderator would be a logical next step. I love Stack Overflow's collaborative editing aspect, that's one the things that drew me to the site.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888260#1888260):** It helps the community in ways that others cannot.  If one appreciates the vital role that those actions play in maintaining the health of the SO ecosystem, then "moderating" and "janitorial tasks" don't take on a negative connotation.  I've never seen them as such because I realize the value those actions have.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888323#1888323):** Two things - slightly obsessive about fixing grammar/spelling/formatting issues and a warm fuzzy feeling from making constructive improvements to things that interest me (i.e. technical Q&A in this instance)

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888390#1888390):** A combination of 1) general satisfaction from helping the community 2) tools that are easy to use to achieve it routinely and regularly

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889418#1889418):** I love grammar, languages, and writing!

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Tim Post] [Tim Post](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888240#1888240):* You edited one of your posts 20 times, the system converted it to CW. You'd like that reverted. As a moderator, what would you do?

---

- **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [asked for clarification](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888252#1888252):** I edited my post? or someone edited their post and is asking?

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888268#1888268):** If it is my post. leave it CW. if it a user's post, see the reason why the edits were made

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888253#1888253):** I wouldn't do so. It would be unfair to the users which want to do so but can't

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888257#1888257):** I leave it as CW. That is not a good use of moderator powers.

**[image: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ] [NullUserException ఠ_ఠ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888276#1888276):** Nothing. The CW conversion was put in place for a reason, using your mod abilities to circumvent that is a slippery slope.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888295#1888295):** I'd ask another moderator to do it; it wouldn't be right for me to make that conversion; there's a conflict of interest there.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888296#1888296):** Leave it.  I don't care about reputation, so why should I take special action on one of my own questions?

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888299#1888299):** I didn't think you could revert it back. If it means that much then just delete it and ask it again. However, you should probably ask yourself why I am editing a post 20 times.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888360#1888360):** I never revert it myself until and unless I ask other mods, and they give it the OK (in which case they'd probably have reverted it for me). 99% of the time, though, I'm not bothered enough by auto-CW to want to revert.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889435#1889435):** Leave it, considering that mod powers are for fixing other people's mistakes, not to let me game the system.

**[image: slugster] [slugster](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/109702/slugster) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1890864#1890864):** If I would do it for a user, then I would do it for myself. IOW, if the edits were over a period of time and done to make it into a truly brilliant and helpful answer, then I would revert it from CW. If not (i.e. the edits were because of slack editing or being lazy with the answer) then it stays CW.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: studiohack] [studiohack](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/306422/studiohack) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888278#1888278):* A fellow mod gets called out by an irate user on Meta.  How do you handle the situation? Ignore the situation? Lend your support? Or?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888291#1888291):** Try to lend support and see what the situation is. if it was blatant then I might act differently

- **[image: studiohack] [studiohack](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/306422/studiohack) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888293#1888293) [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal):** How so?

  **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888298#1888298):** Try to contact the mod via chat

  **[image: studiohack] [studiohack](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/306422/studiohack) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888301#1888301):** Mods always stand together. *always*.

  **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888302#1888302):** privvy

  **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888328#1888328):** Well they should always try to find out the issues together, doesnt mean they agree

  **[image: studiohack] [studiohack](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/306422/studiohack) [clarified](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888340#1888340):** A public united front.

  **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [reiterated](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888346#1888346):** Yes, hence a private chat

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888292#1888292):** I try to intermediate, if it is possible.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888305#1888305):** I would like to get some knowledge about the situation and afterwards, I would try to help

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888329#1888329):** Usually, I've found that the moderator in question can defend themselves quite well in these situations.  If I could provide another perspective on the matter than the person being accused, I would most likely add a polite comment or two.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888334#1888334):** It depends on why the user is irate; if the mod acted in an improper way, then I'd work to resolve the situations.  Loyalty towards other moderators is not assumed with the title, loyalty is earned, and even then, loyalty should not shape moderator decisions; what is best for the community should, first and foremost.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888376#1888376):** It depends what they were called out for - in general though if it looks like a misunderstanding/disagreement I'd try and analyse the situation in an answer and explain why I thought the action the user objected to was taken if they are seeking clarification. If I can't make it better (missing details) I would avoid it though and if it looked *unambiguously* like a genuine accidental click I'd take corrective actions as appropriate

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888405#1888405):** Lend my support.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889447#1889447):** Keep an eye on the situation, try and determine who's right. If the user is correct, privately discuss with the mod and try to work it out with them. Never question another mod in public.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Tim Post] [Tim Post](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888279#1888279):* Through a moderator tool, you found some people near you. Would you reach out to them?

---

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888285#1888285):** No.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888307#1888307):** If there were information on their profile like Twitter usernames and the profile linked to had location information, I might follow them :) Otherwise no.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888310#1888310):** No, not through the use of the tool, it would be through a public venue, such as chat, a comment in the system, or something not related to a tool that I have as a privilege.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888352#1888352):** Probably not.  If people care to be contacted, they generally place such information in their public profile.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888423#1888423):** I wouldn't use privileged information to do so - that would cross a line into stalking in my view. If the public information on their profile solicited social activities I might suggest a pub meetup for example. (My profile doesn't make a big secret of how to contact me and I was a little surprised when a user phoned me recently, but we had a constructive and friendly chat)

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888447#1888447):** (Assuming I interpreted your question correctly) I know I wouldn't say things like "Hey I noticed you're from so-and-so while I was looking at your profile for such-and-such". That's not only creepy, it also gives an impression that I'm using the mod tools specially to scout for people near me, even if I really did just chance upon the person.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889463#1889463):** I consider that to be an abuse of mod powers, to be honest.  Thats not to say that I wouldn't rule it out completely, but most likely not.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ] [NullUserException ఠ_ఠ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888400#1888400):* You actually make a mistake and get called out on meta. An overwhelming amount of users agree with the complaint and protest. How do you respond?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888418#1888418):** Apologize, but not too overtly or else that could come out even worse

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888419#1888419):** I try to fix my error, and I ask apologizes.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888429#1888429):** I would be trying to resolve the situation, revert back the changes if needed.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888436#1888436):** You reverse the decision, simple.  Moderators serve at the pleasure of the community.

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888450#1888450):** Post an answer to the meta post apologising for the error. Revert the action if it's not been done already. It's a mistake - everyone makes them. It's no big deal.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888551#1888551):** Correct the action and learn from the mistake.  We're all human, and we occasionally miss things.  The most important part is to not get angry or defensive, but to realize when you've done something wrong and thank people for pointing it out.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888582#1888582):** Apologize, and see if I can work with the community to follow up and resolve the situation, whatever is necessary.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888697#1888697):** Mistakes are mistakes - everybody makes them (this gets said time and again on meta). The important thing is how they get corrected. I'd do my best to correct the mistake and learn from it for the future.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888995#1888995):** Respectfully back down. If the broad majority of users disagree, then they likely win. Although I'd also mention that it varies by situation. If other mods agree, I'd be more likely to "hold my position".

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Robert Harvey] [Robert Harvey](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888456#1888456):* How important do you believe the use of good grammar, spelling, punctuation and capitalization by users is?  How do you respond to such deficiencies?

---

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888484#1888484):** It's important to allow other users to understand the question being asked, but it should not be the only measure of the posts' quality.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888485#1888485):** I typically edit for such things, I think they are very, very important.  SO prides itself on organic search results.  Because of that, it's important that the content on the site is *quality* content that makes it easier for search engines to do their jobs.  It's also why there is a wiki component to the site; it's so we can constantly refine content to make it better *for all*.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888501#1888501):** Well both of my opinions on that subject were turned down on meta: [Are Stack Exchange sites forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stackoverflow-a-forum) and [Should others downvote my posts for "grammatical" reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/should-others-downvote-my-posts-for-grammatical-reasons) I stand by the 1st one and the lol one I now understand more, but i feel it is not a reason to downvote or ridicule people because of it.

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888505#1888505):** To ask a great question (which is what the site is about yes?) the post needs to be coherent and readable. I'd edit the post and post a comment pointing them to the FAQ and my edit as an example of how to format/spell/construct their question. I'd probably post the link to the article Jon Skeet created for asking questions.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888506#1888506):** To be honest, I'm not so good at English, but I'm always using the correct punctuation and capitalization. When I see a post with some i instead of i, r instead of are, u instead of you, I'm always trying to correct them as my knowledge of English lets me

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888511#1888511):** If it's unreadable, it's an issue - but regardless, I edit the post to correct all issues. It helps people learn good English.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888590#1888590):** Language is not as important as having a good core question.  It's trivial to edit a roughly worded question into shape, but you can't fix truly bad content.  With a growing population of users that don't have English as their native tongue, we have to be willing to help people with their wording, not just reject them outright.  The one exception to this is the use of txtspeak, which really grinds my gears.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888637#1888637):** As long as it makes sense, and doesn't look more like chatspeak/laziness than an imperfect but OK ability to form sentences, I'm fine with it.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888741#1888741):** For non-native English speakers I respect and appreciate the fact that they're making an effort to communicate in a language that might be quite hard for them. for native English speakers it can be an indicator of lazyness which I don't like, however I recognise that even for some native speakers there can be good reasons for poor writing style. As a non-mod I try to fix these. As a mod I would defer to the community generally *unless*...

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888755#1888755):** ...the post was attracting the wrong kind of attention (e.g. abusive comments, close for what was otherwise reasonable)

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888764#1888764):** I do believe proper it is important. Programmers should like proper syntax, right? Posts with a stray missing capitalization are not worthy of an edit, but posts that in really bad shape do.  All of my coworkers are non-native English speakers, they prefer me to correct them.  I've taken this habit to SO.  The only time a post should be deleted because of poor grammar is when it is totally incomprehensible that it is beyond salvage and the user has not cleaned it up.  Nobody's perfect.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889610#1889610):** Spelling and grammar are important for communication. Capitalization is also important. Generally, I'd try to assess where the deficiency stems from. If the user uses textspeak, it's not the same as just plain poor grammar skills. Sometimes it's negligence and sometimes it's a result of lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: badp] [badp](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/13992/badp) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888476#1888476):* As a Stack Overflow moderator, you'll also have moderation powers on this very chat site; unlike all other sites, mods from other sites can't help you. Are you active in chat? Are you aware of the problems chat.SO currently has, if any? Do you have any plans in place for that?

---

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888504#1888504):** I am currently not active in chat, or aware of problems in chat (if there are any, because of said inactivity).  If there are, then my hope is that these would be brought up in meta, and I'd plan on spending some more time in chat to see if/where problems lie.

- **[image: badp] [badp](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/13992/badp) [noted](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888516#1888516):** There used to be trouble with room deduplication or lack thereof and language barrier issues. I don't idle here either, though.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888512#1888512):** I am very active in php and javascript chatrooms. I see a few problems in chat including hyperflagging by some people.

- **[image: badp] [badp](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/13992/badp) [noted](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888524#1888524):** Good news - moderators can see who cast the first flag on all but your chat messages.

  **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888530#1888530):** That would be very very useful ^_^

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888623#1888623):** To be honest, I've tried to get into chat, but the rooms that I've tried using have always been either inactive for days or filled with help vampires and other noise.  I don't understand why chat seems to be so much less robust than the discussions on Meta, and I don't have a good solution for this either.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888826#1888826):** I am active in chat and I've witnessed some of the problems you refer to I think. I don't have a silver bullet solution to it I'm afraid though. I've taken the "make things no worse" path so far, which mostly resulted in doing nothing

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889631#1889631):** I participate both on SO chat, and on Meta chat. I consider myself to be knowledgable in the workings of chat.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Adam Davis] [Adam Davis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888513#1888513):* Have you ever voted to close a post you knew you could edit if you had more time?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888518#1888518):** Yes.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888520#1888520):** No.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888523#1888523):** No.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888527#1888527):** No. That's a wrong step. If I do not have time, I let it as-is. It might be edited by someone else.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888532#1888532):** No, but at the same time, "more time" is subjective.  If I think I can improve a post, I usually favorite it and come back if I don't feel I have "enough time".

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888644#1888644):** I've voted to close questions, then realized how I could edit them into shape afterwards.  I then would generally edit the question and leave behind a comment telling people to ignore my mistaken close vote.

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888649#1888649):** No, I've never closed that could be saved by editing.  I, somewhat masochistically, like to cleanup newbie posts.  If it is beyond my capabilities (eg.: don't know language x well enough to format the code to a presentable state) or time then I'll leave it.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888665#1888665):** Yes, and in that case my close vote is often intended as a chance for the OP to do so.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888870#1888870):** I don't think so on that one - edits that save a question are more far more rewarding than simply closing in my view.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889639#1889639):** No, but I've flagged.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: badp] [badp](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/13992/badp) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888639#1888639):* Where do you come from? Stack Overflow has 6 moderators from the US, 3 from Europe and just poor @TimPost from Oceania. A site this large needs moderation around the clock; how well would you fill in the gaps if you were elected?

---

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888657#1888657):** I come from Europe, and I would fill the gaps, as I have flexibility on when to be on SO.

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888669#1888669):** I'm in Switzerland and generally stay within +/- 1 time zone.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888671#1888671):** I live in NYC, I'm not going to change my sleep schedule to "fill in a gap" (sorry) but I pitch in with all the time I am able to.

- **[image: badp] [badp](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/13992/badp) [clarified](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888674#1888674):** That's not what I meant, I just wanted to give a little chance to mods from non-standard timezones to shine.

  **[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888698#1888698):** Apologies then, take it away @TimPost!!!

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888688#1888688):** I live in London, UK and am usually on around 7am GMT for an hour or so and usually from 4pm until about 9pm GMT. If it's a slow day then I could be active for most of the day too :)

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888689#1888689):** I come from US EST.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888714#1888714):** I'm located in the U.S. Central time zone, so yes, I'm another person from that region.  My heaviest hours are early in the morning, around noon, and later at night.  That spans a bit of time in the day, but others can judge if that is not enough coverage for the growing non-U.S. presence of the site.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888725#1888725):** I'm in Singapore. @TimPost is in the Philippines. We share the same timezone (Southeast Asia). I'm active for many hours in the day, and often find my activity overlapping with users in other timezones. I believe timezone is an important factor in considering me for a position, albeit a small one.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888918#1888918):** I'm from the US, but I'm usually up either early or late, depending on my sleep cycle. I don't think location is that much of an issue for me.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888982#1888982):** GMT/BST depending on time of year - that means I wake up before the US and could start to look at some of the Oceania timezone issue build up relatively promptly still

Comment: Looks like @BoltClock wins this one!  Second place goes to kamlaluno, Stu Thompson, Barry, and awoodland.

Comment: I missed answering this question..l I'm from New Zealand, which is UTC+12, and about 18 hours ahead of EST in the USA. This puts me about 4 hours ahead of BoltClock and Tim Post.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Tim Cooper] [Tim Cooper](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/142162/tim-cooper) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888667#1888667):* Do you feel that SO users with higher reputation are more likely to have their answers voted higher, regardless of the quality?  Do you think that hiding a users' reputation when they answer a question would benefit the site?

---

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888691#1888691):** No, I don't think so, it's more about the speed and quality of the answer

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888773#1888773):** I don't think that hiding their reputation would help. I have never considered a user's reputation when voting

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888692#1888692):** I think that effect definitely does exist.  However, I don't think that hiding rep is the answer, people worked hard to earn it and should be able to have it displayed.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888708#1888708):** I'll also add that I don't think that it's a systemic issue.  Do I care if Jon Skeet gets more rep on an answer than I do even though we have eerily similar answers?  Not in the least.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888699#1888699):** As a user with high reputation on three sites, I can say there is the same chance that my posts are down-voted. Hiding the reputation would not benefit the site; there have been a request to hide who answers, at least for a short time, but the feature didn't have a warm welcome.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888705#1888705):** I believe people are fooled by high rep. When I first started on SO my low rep lead to my answers not being chosen as much. I belive that once you reach a certain point your rep really shouldnt be shown on the page (>10K maybe?)

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888742#1888742):** Actually, that's exactly what I notice with my answers. However, hiding a user's reputation pretty much defeats the purpose and concept of reputation at all, so we might as well rename reputation to something else instead...

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889024#1889024):** I was thinking about this today. There's possibly an element of that, but it's also likely that high rep users are providing better answers, both technically and in terms of presentation and distilling a question to the core point.

**[image: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ] [NullUserException ఠ_ఠ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1892567#1892567):** It does, but I believe hiding the reputation would go against the idea of having the reputation system in the first place. A user with high reputation has shown to have good communication skills and ability to post relevant answers. Why should that be hidden? I don't think hiding reputation would have any discernible effect on the overall quality of answers on the site, but it will drive away some users who are attracted to the gaming aspect of SO.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Adam Davis] [Adam Davis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888694#1888694):* You are hoping to join a very hard working crew. If selected, in what way will you change how much time you spend on site, and when you spend it? If you were asked to set the "minimum hours per week moderating" requirement before a moderator was to be dismissed, what would you say the minimum should be?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888709#1888709):** I am not sure anyone can answer that. It all really depends on the quality of their work

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888712#1888712):** There isn't a minimum; moderating should not be the most predominant activity done in a site, nor the predominant activity done during the day.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888719#1888719):** Mandatory hourly contributions are unfair IMO.  Only if you took a least-common-denominator approach would it be fair.  Everyone performs at different rates, everyone has varying amounts of time.  And remember, this is a community-driven site.  If you feel a moderator isn't doing what they should, or enough, then I'd recommend bringing it up in meta and opening a slot for the next election.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888733#1888733):** I'd simply be grateful that there are people willing to step up and do the work that is asked of them with no expectation of remuneration in return.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888720#1888720):** I spend a lot of time on Stack Overflow, so I think this wouldn't be a problem for me, and I'd say that there shouldn't be a minimum

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888760#1888760):** This would depend on the work load required to deal with the amount of flags, etc. on the site, given the number of moderators available.  I don't believe that there was a definite answer to number of hours or number of flags required in the related Meta discussion on this topic, so I think this will be a matter of feel rather than hard numbers.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889134#1889134):** I don't think my time on the site would change hugely. My use of mod tools (10k and otherwise) clearly would but I'm not going to make unsustainable promises. As far as minimum hours per week goes I don't think it's a great metric, people take holidays etc. I'd say the alarm bells should ring when a mod is out of touch through a lack of activity but defining a solid figure without good data to begin with seems premature

**[image: slugster] [slugster](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/109702/slugster) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1890557#1890557):** IMO, 3 hours a day or more is a good minimum benchmark. Personally I spend considerably more time than this so being elected would not mean I had to change my attendance pattern. Of course I say this without knowing the specifics of exactly how much mod work needs to be chewed through per day, but IMO if you can't spend the 3 hours then you are only a light user of the site.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Adam Davis] [Adam Davis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888779#1888779):* It seems some candidates feel that moderation is something they can do during the existing time they spend on site.  Do you feel you have a good grasp of what you'll spend your time doing, and that you'll be able to do so without adjusting your current schedule?

---

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888803#1888803):** I think I can do it without adjusting my current schedule. If I moderate most of the time, I would get worried of the decisions I take.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888814#1888814):** I think I do. I just will have to be more careful with my decisions.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888821#1888821):** There are two questions in there; I admit openly that I don't understand completely (see my "getting over the hill" section in my nomination) what moderation will bring, but that doesn't mean I'm completely ignorant of what is required of me or what I'll be able to do.  To answer the second, yes, I'll easily be able to do so without adjusting my schedule.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888841#1888841):** Yes, I have a rough idea. I can imagine myself doing the same thing I'm doing now, only with slightly more moderation work and less answering. I don't think one's going to adversely affect the other.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888863#1888863):** Yes, I'll. I decide a lot of time on Stack Overflow, so it's not a problem for me to divide normal participation and moderation duties

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888865#1888865):** I'd definitely have to adjust my reunite, but that does not scare me.  For the most part my editing/flagging activity has usually been a task I enjoy--fun time for when I can squeeze it in.  If similar tasks like moderation were a duty, a responsibility, then that would be motivational.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889267#1889267):** I think I already do a fair amount of moderation. How my time is spent clearly would shift to focus on different tasks, but fundamentally not a huge change for my usage patterns.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Rebecca Chernoff] [Rebecca Chernoff](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/181481/rebecca-chernoff) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888964#1888964):* Final thoughts from the candidates?

---

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888970#1888970):** Where are the sandwiches I have heard of?

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888973#1888973):** Same as last night, **thank you**, it's a wonderful experience, and I'm happy to be here among so many other qualified candidates.  Thank you for the opportunity, and no matter what, SO is going to be better off as a result.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888988#1888988):** **Thanks and have a great day! ^_^**

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888990#1888990):** This was just as stressful as the last, but I'm glad to have experienced it.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889001#1889001):** I would like to thank you for the chance to participate here, it was a wonderful experience. Have a nice day!

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889453#1889453):** Thanks if you've voted for me so far. (If you're hesitant I'd be glad to chat more - I'm regularly in the C++ chat room if I've got a web browser to hand) I'd like more moderator tools to increase the usefulness of the things I do. In exchange for that I'll do my best to be fair, efficient and reflect the will of the community.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Adam Davis] [Adam Davis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888026#1888026):* What is the moderator's role in site promotion, and how do you see yourself fulfilling that role?

---

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888045#1888045):** Moderators are akin to ambassadors; they should serve as examples of what the community on SO should be, and their actions, public or private, should be reflective of that.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888068#1888068):** Moderators promote the site through their actions. Anything that makes it a better site implicitly promotes the site

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888105#1888105):** Moderator's don't promote, that role is already filled by others.  Moderators keep the site nice-n-tidy.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888118#1888118):** Aside from what [@StuThompson said](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888105#1888105) (which I agree with), I can only think of spreading word of SO via social media, and in my school, for now. I don't know many programmers beyond these two.

Comment: It should be noted that I was more directly answering [a question that Tim Post asked me](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888067#1888067), based in our location and timezone.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ] [NullUserException ఠ_ఠ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888064#1888064):* There are 20+ candidates and 4 slots. Why should I elect you instead of someone else? What do you bring to the table the others don't?

---

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888132#1888132):** I'll defer to my answer given last night: [November 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest #1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112443/november-2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest-1/112453#112453) =)

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889086#1889086):** I'm great with grammar and spelling, and, I *enjoy* editing.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Mr. Disappointment] [Mr. Disappointment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/263681/mr-disappointment) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888084#1888084):* Are you aware of the implications the role will have on your current mode of contribution, and how do you intend to adapt your mode-of-use (i.e. in terms of planning daily rounds, or on-the-fly handling as and when)?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888110#1888110):** A mix. would mostly be doing rouns in the mid day Eastern time, but at other points I will moderate as well.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888112#1888112):** As it stands, I spend most of my time on the site performing moderation-related tasks, so it would not affect the overall way I use the site.  If anything, it would make some of the things I do more efficient, because I would not need to bring in another moderator to deal with items.  I keep generally regular hours here.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888116#1888116):** I don't think my contributions would change massively overnight - I think I would probably carry on most of the things I do, but transition, by learning through observation how/where the new tools would be appropriate. The end result would be a shift away from the tasks which can be handled already by the community (which I've been doing already) towards the tasks that only moderators can handle

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888121#1888121):** I mentioned "getting over the hump" in my nomination, there will be a time that I'm learning the ropes, but I expect that the change, while drastic, will not be unmanageable.  It's simply a new phase in what I'm trying to do at SO, help others, which I welcome.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888140#1888140):** I am, but from what I see, the most that would happen to me is that I spend less time answering questions than performing other routine duties. And even then I don't quite foresee such a radical change in how I use the site.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889154#1889154):** I used to ask a lot of questions, but at one point I began answering more. Then I started to edit more. I'll probably continue to edit more, and use the 10K tools more often.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Tim Cooper] [Tim Cooper](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/142162/tim-cooper) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888086#1888086) genesis and minitech:* Being two of the youngest candidates (under 18), do you feel that there could be age discrimination towards yourselves that could hinder your ability to moderate?

---

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888095#1888095):** Sure there could. I think however, that I would be able to handle that.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888104#1888104):** Age discrimination? For sure. However, I don't believe it would hinder anyone's ability to moderate. I don't intend to start any fights with anyone, and I'll show people that age is no problem by making good moderation decisions.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Robert Harvey] [Robert Harvey](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888139#1888139):* What is your "fundamental principle of moderation?" That is, what is your top-level principle you will fall back on that will help you make decisions in borderline situations?

---

- **[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [asked for clarification](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888155#1888155):** Can you give an example of borderline decisions?

  **[image: Robert Harvey] [Robert Harvey](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888165#1888165):** A close/open war, a technical dispute, content that might be perceived as promoting illegal behaviour.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888153#1888153):** I'll ask myself "does this action as a moderator help the community?".  If the answer is ever no, then I will not perform that action.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889228#1889228):** Be intellectually honest and avoid controversy.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888164#1888164):** Moderators are human handler exceptions; if the community didn't report something as wrong, then the community thinks the situation is fine.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888171#1888171):** My fundamental principle would be "don't make problems worse" - that means stepping back if I can't be objective and it means looking for advice if I don't know what the right action to take is

**[image: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ] [NullUserException ఠ_ఠ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888180#1888180):** "Be nice." A moderator is there to *serve* the community. That's not to say moderators should be subservient to the community - you should be gentle yet decisive. And that's an art.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888219#1888219):** First, will the community handle this on their own?  If so, it doesn't need my intervention.  Moderators must handle the extreme outer cases (non-answers, spam, etc.) that users can't deal with.  When in doubt, my policy would be to either ask other moderators, bring it to the community via Meta, or leave an item alone.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888236#1888236):** I would say [I know it when I see it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it), but for borderline situations, well, I believe there are others more experienced whom I can look to for assistance. I pretty much defer to them in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Shog9] [Shog9](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888163#1888163):* How familiar are you with the use of [the 10K tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) on Stack Overflow?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888169#1888169):** Semi familiar. I have mostly been doing edits and flagging.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888174#1888174):** I am a 20k user on a site, and a 10k users on other two sites. I use the 10k tools in all of them.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888182#1888182):** Familiar enough to use them almost every day.  I've been at 10k for a while.  Admittedly, there's always more I can learn (for example, I don't look at the breakdown of answers by vote groupings nearly enough), but I'm familiar enough to help with the 10K rep moderation duties.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888206#1888206):** I know most of the tools and I use them every day

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888209#1888209):** Of the 10k tools I've used the deletion ones the least and the "new answers to old questions" which I've found to be the easiest way of finding posts that require intervention outside of the flag queue itself, which I use fairly regularly also.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888217#1888217):** Fairly familiar. I still haven't handled any spam.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888247#1888247):** As some of the current moderators can attest, I'm way too familiar with these tools.  They've evolved significantly since I first got access to them, and I'm definitely enjoying the new review system for answers and close votes.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888319#1888319):** I spend most time in the overview and on close votes, but I've explored and invested learning effort into all the tools.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889368#1889368):** Fairly familiar.

Comment: Related: [Pubby's question "How familiar are you with moderation tools?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112443/november-2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest-1/112457#112457) from the last chat cast.  That was answered by jonsca, Moshe, and Anna Lear.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Tim Post] [Tim Post](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888185#1888185):* You have several flags indicating 'very low quality' on a single post; you can't find any obvious issues with the post. What do you do?

---

- **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [asked for clarification](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888189#1888189):** Can you elaborate?

  **[image: Tim Post] [Tim Post](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888200#1888200):** Three users have said 'this post has serious issues, it should be deleted' you don't see anything wrong with it.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888195#1888195):** Bring it up in meta, chat with other mods about it at first.  See if they might see something you've missed.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888205#1888205):** I would ask on meta and see what people say there.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888208#1888208):** The flags are invalid, then.

- **[image: Tim Cooper] [Tim Cooper](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/142162/tim-cooper) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888238#1888238) [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech):** Are you saying that you are so sure of your own personal judgement not to investigate the matter further?

  **[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888272#1888272):** Well, if there's nothing obviously wrong, then it's not "very low quality." Something else might be an issue, and if that were the case and I wasn't sure what to do with it, I would ask on MSO.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888220#1888220):** I check the revisions of the posts, and if effectively there is something that indicates a low quality post, I flag it as valid. "Low quality" flags should not replace down-votes, though.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888230#1888230):** I would ask someone for their opinion, or let the flag be marked as resolved by someone else

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888251#1888251):** Obviously check any edits that may have changed the quality of the post. Then check out the User. Either previous history available to mods or chat with a few other mods to see if the user has been in any conflicts with other users. If they are all negative then dismiss the flags.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888277#1888277):** Usually, this indicates a decent question that is phrased poorly.  In the past, I've edited such questions into shape and seen a good response to that.  I'd do so and dismiss the existing flags.  I doubt that the flags would return.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888282#1888282):** Check the revision history - it's quite likely if a post has seen that much attention that someone else has fixed the problem whilst the flags were waiting in the queue

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888324#1888324):** Read the comments, if any, and go from there.  Maybe have a look at the flagger's flagging history and look for a pattern: targeted flagging of a specific user, etc.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888331#1888331):** Ask on meta if I'm not sure, otherwise I cancel the flags.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889405#1889405):** If I'm unfamiliar with the subject, defer to other mods. If I'm certain that it's fine, dispute the flags.

**[image: slugster] [slugster](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/109702/slugster) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1890836#1890836):** I have noticed this actually is the case with some of the VLQ flags in the queue. VLQ is a matter of opinion, but I wonder sometimes if they are raised maliciously on answers... in any case, I would prefer that people down vote and save the VLQ flags for the truly low quality posts. I've posted on meta about this before: [The scourge of the Very Low Quality flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94783/the-scourge-of-the-very-low-quality-flag)

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Tim Post] [Tim Post](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888306#1888306):* Someone has dug up some bad things in your history, and questioned an action you took based on that. How will you deal with that?

---

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888347#1888347):** I would try to remember what happened, and in case that was my fault, I would do the action needed to rollback the action

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888461#1888461):** I would try to remember the situation, and in case I would think that I was really wrong, I would admit it and try to help to resolve the problems issued

**[image: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ] [NullUserException ఠ_ఠ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888365#1888365):** It depends. Was it the result of a policy change? If so, should the policy be applied retroactively or should the old content be grandfathered? That probably falls on Jeff. If not, and I truly made a bad call, I'll admit the mistake and correct it.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888372#1888372):** I would ask the user to correlate the bad actions in my history with the action at hand.  If there's a correlation, then I'd address the action to resolve it, if not, I'd not address it, but in the interest of transparency, bring it up with other mods to make the final decision.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888434#1888434):** I use my real name on the site and elsewhere because I stand behind what I say online.  I'm confident that I could defend things I've said in the past, or at least explain my reasoning at the time I said it.  I can also admit mistakes that I've made before and how I've learned from them since.

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888451#1888451):** Call a press conference and deny everything!  (Seriously...)  I'd keep my response to the facts of the action I took: explain what I did, why I did it, and that is the only reason for my action.  I'd also reach out to another moderator and give them a heads up.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888496#1888496):** If I agreed with their assessment I'd take appropriate corrective action. If I disagreed I'd defer to seek a second opinion.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889521#1889521):** Back down where appropriate. There's no reason to entertain confrontation.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: random] [random](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888308#1888308):* You closed a question. That OP later finds your home phone number, calls you up at 3am and asks for you to clarify the reasoning. How many days should they be suspended?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888338#1888338):** 42 days

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888341#1888341):** The user would not get any suspension, from me.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888342#1888342):** Hm... if anyone calls that early, I don't even answer.

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888357#1888357):** My phone number is fairly easy to find, borderline public.   So none...after the first call, where I tell them something like "This is not an appropriate phone call, we need to keep our communication within the confines of StackOverflow".

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888383#1888383):** There's a larger issue than suspending them for SO; all due respect to the system, my first concern is to protect myself and my family, so I would call the police first.  I'd bring it up on meta second.  I'd let Jeff, Joel, and the community decide.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888546#1888546):** My home phone number doesn't ring at 3am so I can't get awoken in appropriately. Timezones might account for odd hours to phone at. My action would depend on the tone. If the user was abusive I would consider taking action, but not if it was a genuine plea for help (I don't know what typical suspension times are, I'm not even sure it would be the right tool though so the first step would be to find out what a proportionate response would be)

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889534#1889534):** I wouldn't be the one to handle it. I'd defer punishment to another mod.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Mr. Disappointment] [Mr. Disappointment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/263681/mr-disappointment) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888335#1888335):* With some of your actions no longer going through an 'authoritative filter', what influence do you think this will have, if any, on your speed of decision making?

---

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888350#1888350):** None. (I never make decisions like that based on personal issues.)

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888358#1888358):** Not much

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888359#1888359):** "Measure Twice, Cut Once". I would consider the action twice before doing so.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888368#1888368):** It will just influence the actions for which other users can act on, and for which I would wait for any response from other users.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888402#1888402):** My decision making might be slightly impacted.  As a moderator, one has to be aware of the impact of their decisions.  That doesn't mean I'd make my decisions out of haste.  The impact of being a moderator will always factor into my decisions.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888454#1888454):** I will be more deliberate in my actions, because I won't be able to defer to the community on close or delete votes to see if others agree with my thoughts.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888535#1888535):** I'll be more cautious with my close and delete votes depending on the situation, and only cast if I'm 100% sure something has to be closed or isn't worth keeping.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888586#1888586):** My current actions are mostly via votes (flags are effectively votes that moderators set the bar on). That means if I'm not sure a "vote/flag" is implicitly a question to others with similar or greater voting powers. Without that ability to seek a consensus my actions would be reduced  to the cases where there is far less doubt involved.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888976#1888976):** I'm sure that my answer to this will be change based on experience. At first I'll start slowly, but as I become more comfortable, I'll move faster.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Adam Davis] [Adam Davis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888384#1888384):* As the site has grown the community has chosen to become more exclusionary in their approach to poor questions.  Do you see the site as more or less approachable, and more or less fun than when you started?  Is the current level of exclusion and fun appropriate, or do you feel it would be good to nudge it in one direction or another?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888394#1888394):** Yes, it has become much more serious than even one year ago. I am not sure what one mod can do about that, but I can try.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888397#1888397):** It is as fun as it was before. Poor questions don't make the site funnier.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888428#1888428):** I don't think exclusion of someone who genuinely wants to participate and be part of our community in any form is acceptable.  I don't like how SO is becoming more exclusionary.  We can change that however, with better approaches towards those that we feel "shouldn't" be here to make them valued members of the community.

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888431#1888431):** It is less forgiving than it used to be. I think it needs to cut some people some slack - especially new users. A gentle nudge in the right direction (FAQ, editing questions/answers) not just straight closing everything. If posts get closed yes they can be reopened but I don't feel it's immediately clear to new users.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888528#1888528):** At the risk of being a spoilsport, the primary mission of Stack Overflow is not to have fun, but to help people find solutions to their problems.  There are plenty of outlets for jokes, cartoons, etc. on the Internet, and Stack Overflow doesn't need to be another one.  I think the recent quality filters and other improvements have done a great job in managing incoming content quality.

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888609#1888609):** It's not as fun as it used to be when I started, but those days where filled with self-selected interested coders who were exploring a new land of J&J's creation.  Now the that the roads are not only defined, but pathed with ample sign posts, the community needs everyone to accept the now formalized rules of the road.  All this development has given SO users outlets for their 'fun' needs, including a sandbox for the kids (chat).

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888666#1888666):** I don't think it's any less approachable for users who ask good questions (they're still well received). I think it might be less approachable to users who don't ask good question - the key thing here is that they're fed appropriate constructive advice. Good questions are fun questions in my view - "fix this code I've not shown you" or "do my job for me" aren't fun.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888672#1888672):** I think the appropriate direction to take would be better feedback in the case of well intentioned, but poorly executed questions (and answers) from new users.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Tim Post] [Tim Post](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888446#1888446) [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) :* How much time (daily) do you have to devote to janitorial tasks?

---

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888488#1888488):** In the range of 2-4 hours, scattered throughout the day, with interruptions from occasional commitments like conferences and other events.  I have a fairly flexible work schedule, given our small company.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888568#1888568) [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) :* What do you think of all the criticism you've received due to your past behavior?  Is it fair or not?

---

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888584#1888584):** It is fair. I have done a lot of mistakes before, I have admitted it. I'm trying to chang as I'm being older on Stack Exchange and trying to make the site better place to stay

- **[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [countered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888597#1888597):** Do you feel they are truly mistakes?  Many people say it was intentional.

  **[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888616#1888616):** You have to trust me, no mistake I have done here wasn't an intentional. I am not even sure why would I want to do that

  **[image: quantumSoup] [quantumSoup](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/370483/quantumsoup) [questioned](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888687#1888687):** You have received a lot of criticism from a few users in particular. How would that affect your moderation when it comes to posts made these users?

  **[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888711#1888711):** I would be more careful (and I'm) (and even more when moderating) after these accidents and I would firstly learn from my mistakes.

Comment: These answers are very hard to understand. How can we elect a moderator who can't write clear sentences in English? I understand there is a language barrier and I'm sympathetic, but there is no denying this would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: random] [random](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888613#1888613):* New users now have to register to ask on SO. Was this a good idea or the greatest idea ever? What other measures might help SO from getting reamed so violently and so often?

---

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888634#1888634):** Greatest idea ever?  Perhaps you'd want to make that "Greatest idea ever on SO" =)  I run an SO clone and I've found registration through OpenID/OA to be invaluable in keeping out spam.  It is a small price to ask people to pay to maintain the general health of the community.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888648#1888648):** However, I do feel that becoming an identity provider puts strain on the development team, because now, security and attacks on that security are additional burdens they have to deal with.  I trust in them, but less burdens there are, the more they can focus on other issues.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888638#1888638):** It was necessary. It could not have been the greatest idea, but it would have been a worse idea not to take any action.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888641#1888641):** It was a good idea, I think. There were many people which have been using this to spam the site

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888675#1888675):** I cannot think of a single disadvantage to this. I'd always thought not requiring any registration in any form was a backdoor to spam, if not a front door (as well-defended SO is against spam...).

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888682#1888682):** I think it was a good idea. and renaming adds flavorr ^_^

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888899#1888899):** I personally hate the idea of collecting logins on every website that I visit, but enforcing OpenID login here provides some sort of necessary accountability. What do you mean by "reamed so violently"?

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888921#1888921):** This looks like it was a good move from what I've seen. I might be in favour of some kind of "question purgatory" for first questions which could be handled by comparatively low rep users for a rep bonus, but I'm not too sure on that one. I definitely don't favour a two-tier system as has been proposed on meta a few times in the past

**[image: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ] [NullUserException ఠ_ఠ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1892566#1892566):** Considering the policy change came after I [suggested a change in that direction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it), I think it's a good idea. My reasoning behind it is in the aforementioned suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Xeon06] [Xeon06](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/104999/xeon06) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888723#1888723):* If you do not get elected to this election for any reason, do you plan on entering the next?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888727#1888727):** For sure ^_^

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888728#1888728):** Sure I would try to do so.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888730#1888730):** Yes. I think I can contribute, and I would try the next elections.

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888734#1888734):** Yes

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888758#1888758):** Yes sir!  It's a great experience.  I (obviously) wasn't elected last election, and I've come to appreciate the moderator position more in that time; last election, I just "threw my hat in the ring", this time, I'm all out.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888778#1888778):** For me, as much as I want to, I can't admit much honestly - it depends on what happens in the next year. Private personal issues to deal with, and such.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888844#1888844):** It depends on if I still feel that I would be able to help in the position.  I ran last time and didn't make it past the primaries, yet I looked at it and still felt like I could take some of the load off of the existing moderators. I'm still content helping out as a non-moderator by acting as a 20k user and flagging, voting to close, and voting to delete bad content.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888939#1888939):** Yes.

**[image: Stu Thompson] [Stu Thompson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888945#1888945):** If not elected, I'd only enter the next election if the pool of available candidates was equally as select as this election. Being a moderator is not something I'd actively considered or desired until discovering that SO considered my a viable candidate.  It sounds mushy, but I've been flattered by the support I've received so far.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889160#1889160):** If I don't get elected my views on the site won't change. I'd probably re-run baring some major change

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Shog9] [Shog9](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888762#1888762):* Philosophical question: editing to correct flaws in other user's answers: merely admirable, or worthy of a medal?

---

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888768#1888768):** It's worth a badge.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888771#1888771):** I think its admirable. Whose to say that those corrections are `correct`? :-D

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888782#1888782):** Depends on the flaw.  Remember, we are never supposed to make an edit which changes the intent.  Assuming that the change is not to change the intent, it's always admirable.  Whether or not it's worthy of the badge depends on the quality of the edit (adding a missing semi-colon to the end of some C# code is *not* worthy of a badge, but admirable).  In short, always admirable, sometimes worthy of a badge.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888793#1888793):** I do not think that it would be admirable. I'm correcting other's answers, if possible, to help them, not to get medals. If the flaws are in grammar/spelling, they should be edited, not otherwise, not to change the intention

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888807#1888807):** Most of such edits that I commit would be too minor to deserve a real reward IMO. Those that do would be too substantial and could potentially change the meaning of posts, which is something I'd rather not deal with.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889203#1889203):** Depends how big the flaw was - I wouldn't edit to correct a major flaw (that would be changing the meaning of the answer in my view). I'd probably comment and vote with a view to changing the vote once the flaw was corrected if it was major

**[image: slugster] [slugster](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/109702/slugster) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1890580#1890580):** Worthy of a medal once enough has been done. The badge is to reward consistent behaviour, without it people would be less inclined to be admirable for long periods of time :)

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: random] [random](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888822#1888822):* Another mod spends their time on the site just answering questions, rarely touching flags and only closing when it happens to be something they come across while looking for more things to answer. How would you oust them from a position they're clearly not interested in?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888846#1888846):** Have a meeting of the minds with them and find out what is going on

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888850#1888850):** Send them a chat message in the Mod Chat room and ask them why they are answering questions all the time instead of moderating. No point in cloak and daggers when you can just ask them outright. Ask them if they want to carry on with their moderator duties.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888856#1888856):** Mention it to them first in private (Mod chat or email), try to clarify, perhaps encourage them to be more involved. Then I'd let other the senior mods deal with it.

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888866#1888866):** It's not up to me to oust him.  It's up to the community.  Make a case in meta; bring up a suggestion on how to address those kinds of moderators as a feature request.  Being an [MVP](http://mvp.support.microsoft.com/), I'm used to having to retain responsibilities; it's not something you achieve once and then you are forever an MVP, we are re-evaluated every year for the award.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888887#1888887):** I could try to talk to them about it, but if any real action needs to be taken I leave it to the other mods.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889320#1889320):** I don't think it's particularly my place to "oust" anyone. I hope that the answer to "who will mod the mods?" would lead to more senior people (e.g. SE employees) spotting such things

**[image: slugster] [slugster](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/109702/slugster) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1890708#1890708):** You need to raise it with them first, remind them that modding is a duty and responsibility, not just the ultimate badge. You then discuss your concerns with the other mods. If enough agree then you can form a witch-burning mob and.... ask them to step down.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: quantumSoup] [quantumSoup](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/370483/quantumsoup) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888831#1888831):* Say you are elected,  but due to unforeseen circumstances, you ca no longer dedicate enough to moderation. Do you resign?

---

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888834#1888834):** Yes.

**[image: Moshe] [Moshe](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888840#1888840):** Yes.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888849#1888849):** Yes.

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888875#1888875):** Yes. If you know that you can't dedicate enough time that is required then you should resign. Another person can be elected and take the work load. If you were doing a good job you can always nominate yourself again in another election (providing you can dedicate enough time of course)

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888879#1888879):** Yes, if I cannot perform the responsibilities delegated to me because of other circumstances, then I'd resign, and I'd do it graciously, content that I was able to help while I could.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888883#1888883):** Sure. I do not think that it would happen though, until I have some serious problems with the school

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888917#1888917):** Yes, and I do my best to explain why if circumstances permit me to do so, in order to be accountable.

**[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888953#1888953):** Of course.  It's not helpful to occupy a post that you're no longer capable of acting on.  This can help the site administrators better know when to run new elections.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889335#1889335):** That would depend on how long term and how low the lack of dedication would be, but I think it would be the right thing to do for long term low activity

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: quantumSoup] [quantumSoup](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/370483/quantumsoup) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888891#1888891):* You find out that a fellow moderator is possibly engaging in questionable behavior, like having sockpuppets upvoting their posts. How do you handle the situation?

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888903#1888903):** Again. meeting of the minds. private chat to see what is going on.

**[image: genesis] [genesis](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888908#1888908):** I would discus it with the other mods, and with the mod which has the sock puppet account. I do not think this is even possible to happen

**[image: Barry] [Barry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/300863/barry) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888912#1888912):** Check it out and if they are, contact the team and let them know. Banning them won't work as they are moderator. by team I mean team@stackoverflow.com

**[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888923#1888923):** Again, bring it up in meta; meta is the perfect venue for these types of actions.  One of the reasons it exists is to **ask what to do when we don't know what to do**.

- **[image: quantumSoup] [quantumSoup](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/370483/quantumsoup) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888932#1888932) [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone):** So you would publicly expose the mod?

  **[image: casperOne] [casperOne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888965#1888965):** Not in meta, at first, plenty of people's actions have been questioned in meta without exposing the person themselves.  If the discussion in meta showed a resolution, then I'd enact it as a mod, referencing the original discussion in meta.

**[image: BoltClock] [BoltClock](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1888928#1888928):** Report it to the other mods and the team immediately.

**[image: awoodland] [awoodland](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/awoodland) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1889364#1889364):** Avoiding a confrontation here would be best. that probably means an email to 'team@', although a private chat might be appropriate if possible

**[image: slugster] [slugster](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/109702/slugster) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1890756#1890756):** Treat them the same as any other user, they shouldn't get preferential treatment in this area just because they are a mod. But having said that, I would expect a mod to be of good character and not engage (or even need to engage) in that sort of behaviour.